# Text Selection In Android Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

to select text in web view below code is working fine

```
KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0,0,KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT,0,0)                       
shiftPressEvent.dispatch(webView);
```

but that dispatch method is deprecated. so instead of that i like to use this

```
 public final boolean dispatch (KeyEvent.Callback receiver, KeyEvent.DispatcherState state, Object target)
```

give me an idea from the above function to select text.

Answer (score 3):

I got web view selections working in 2.2 - 4.0.3 using a javascript interface that gets all touches passed to it. The solution seems to work pretty well and I've put an example project on github. The github project includes the necessary js in the assets folder as well as a test page and web view that loads the test page and implements all necessary methods to handle the selection. The link to the github project is https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection. Have at it.